# Lua script - Multi key while mouse button pressed, stop on release

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

Good Morning,

I currently have a macro ("Loop") recorded in Logitech that does the following:

120 delay, Key 1, 90 delay, left click, 150 delay, Key 2, 90 delay, left click, 140 delay

It is set to toggle. I then utilize the following script:

```
local flag
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 20 then
      PlayMacro("Loop")
   end
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 20 then
      AbortMacro()
   end
end
```

This works well, however... :D Obviously all the delays after the left click are the same with every repeat. I would like them to be random between 120 and 160. Sadly I'm a hopeless LUA noob, so I did some googling and attempted to move away from a macro and throw it all into the lua script, however I'm doing something wrong as all it does is press 1 without stopping:

```
local flag
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 20 then
      Sleep(math.random(120, 160))
      PressKey("1")
      Releasekey("1")
      Sleep(90)
      PressMouseButton(1)
      ReleaseMouseButton(1)
      Sleep(math.random(120, 160))
      PressKey("2")
      Releasekey("2")
      Sleep(90)
      PressMouseButton(1)
      ReleaseMouseButton(1)
   end   
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 20 then
      return
   end
end
```

What am I missing?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: It should not matter, but for a single click you can use `PressAndReleaseKey()` and `PressAndReleaseMouseButton()`

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.**
Do you use Mouse Button 4 ("Back") in the game?

- If YES (some action is set to MB#4 in the game), proceed to "Step 2".
- If NO (the game ignores MB#4 press), skip "Step 2" and proceed to "Step 3".

---

**Step 2.**
You have to remap the game action from MB#4 to some other key.
Do the following:

- choose keyboard key you don't currently use in the game
  (let's assume the `F12` key is not currently used)
- go to the big mouse picture in LGS and assign command `F12` to your physical MB#4
- go to your game settings and set the game action to `F12` instead of MB#4

As a result, when you press physical MB#4, the game receives `F12` and activates the game action.
Now skip "Step 3" and proceed to "Step 4".

---

**Step 3.**
Go to the big mouse picture in LGS.
Unassign standard command "Back" from physical MB#4 (select "Unassign" from the drop-down menu).

---

**Step 4.**
Go to the big mouse picture in LGS.
Assign command "Back" to your physical button G20.

---

**Step 5.**
Set the script

```
local function InterruptableSleep(ms)
   local tm = GetRunningTime() + ms
   while GetRunningTime() < tm do
      Sleep(5)
      if not IsMouseButtonPressed(4) then return true end
   end
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 20 then
      repeat
         if InterruptableSleep(math.random(120, 160)) then break end
         PressKey("1")
         Releasekey("1")
         if InterruptableSleep(90) then break end
         PressMouseButton(1)
         ReleaseMouseButton(1)
         if InterruptableSleep(math.random(120, 160)) then break end
         PressKey("2")
         Releasekey("2")
         if InterruptableSleep(90) then break end
         PressMouseButton(1)
         ReleaseMouseButton(1)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(4)  -- 4 = "Back"
   end
end
```

Comment: Sorry I don't follow Step 1 through 4. The game action that I am trying to achieve are the key presses in the script above. So pressing number keys, clicking the left mouse button and having delays in between.

So my goal is rattle off the multi key combo while I hold G20 (repeat if need be) and stop when I release it.

Comment: `So my goal is rattle off the multi key combo while I hold G20 (repeat if need be) and stop when I release it.` - Yes, that's exactly what my solution is designed for.  The task can not be solved by only writing a script.  What problems do you have with steps 1-4 ?

Comment: What confuses me is this..
Step 3: Unassign "Back" from M4
Step 4: Assign back to G20
Script: IsMouseButtonPressed(4)  -- 4 = "Back"

I don't understand the logic behind this.

Comment: Also, the way that it's posted now doesn't interrupt when I release the button as my original setup intended

  ->
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 20 then
      return
   end
end

Comment: `doesn't interrupt when I release the button` - your loop is only a half second, why do you want to interrupt it in the middle? :-)  I guess it is ok here to wait until the current iteration ends.

Comment: `IsMouseButtonPressed(4) -- 4 = "Back" I don't understand the logic behind this` - Because IsMouseButtonPressed(20) does not work in LGS, so a workaround with button 4 is needed.

Comment: Because I need to be able to stop the sequence and restart it at will. Can you please help me change this so that it stops when I let go of G20?

Comment: I only posted a short part of the actual script. It runs 20sec

Comment: Script updated.